# What's the text on this MAKE ... GREAT AGAIN hat?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

Per this article 
http://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-trump-visa-idUSKBN17K02U:

> U.S. President Donald Trump is given a hat by Wisconsin Governor Scott
>   Walker (R) as he arrives at the world headquarters of Snap-On Inc, a
>   tool manufacturer, in Kenosha, Wisconsin, U.S., April 18, 2017.

[image: Trump with green hat]

I can't read the text on the hat. It appears to say "MAKE THE ?????? GREAT AGAIN". (Of course I don't know the word replaced by question marks)

I've tried a Google News Search, a Google Image Search (using the image URL), and also [Tiny Eye](https://www.tineye.com/search/e5e2a337cd00d2ccefe4e3d48cc11efae79ce7e0/).

But I can't read the key word. What does the title on the hat say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make the [Bucks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milwaukee_Bucks) Great Again.**

The governor is holding a jersey for that sports team.